# How do I parse this kinda json which has different names , or tel me how do I even display this response in recycler view. :(

Tags: android, json, kotlin, serialization, retrofit

```
{ 
   "code":200,
   "response":{ 
      "Categories":{ 
         "12345":{ 
            "name":"Category1",
            "image":"image1URL"
         },
         "23456":{ 
            "name":"Category2",
            "image":"image2URL"
         },
         "34567":{ 
            "name":"Category13",
            "image":"image3URL"
         },
         "45678":{ 
            "name":"Category14",
            "image":"image4URL"
         },
         "56789":{ 
            "name":"Category15",
            "image":"image5URL"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Its like it has all uids in it. I have no clue and i need help real quick and one last thing, I cant ask them to modify.

Comment: Does your interviewer know you're posting this question here?

Comment: @enzo of course not. :p but I have a day time to finish this. also it's for my learning, CZ if not how else will I ever know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the object by using `JSONObject` (org.json library) and iterate over the keys of the children elements of `videoCategories` like this:

```
val videoCategories = JSONObject(jsonString).getJSONObject("response").getJSONObject("videoCategories")
videoCategories.keys().forEach { uuid ->
    Log.v("JSONParsing", "uuid: $uuid")
}
```

Or, of course, use other collection operations (like `map`) to convert the particular elements to model objects, which you could use in the recycler view adapter:

```
val videoCategories = JSONObject(jsonString).getJSONObject("response").getJSONObject("videoCategories")
val categories = videoCategories.keys().map { uuid ->
    val categoryObject = videoCateories.getJSONObject(uuid)
    val name = categoryObject.getString("name")
    val image = categoryObject.getString("image")
    Category(uuid, name, image)
}
```